# Unable to listen to twilio video javascript endpoint

Tags: javascript, twilio, twilio-php

I am using twilio video javascript service. When i try to listen to a endpoint, its giving an error :

```
{_errorData: Object, name: "LISTEN_FAILED", message: "Gateway responded with: 31201 Authentication failed"}
```

I am generating access token using below code :

```
<?php
    require_once('/path/to/twilio-php/Services/Twilio.php');

    $accountSid = "ACC_SID";
    $signingKeySid = SID;
    $signingKeySecret = SECRET;

    $token = new Services_Twilio_AccessToken($signingKeySid, $accountSid, $signingKeySecret);
    $token->addEndpointGrant(ENDPOINT_NAME);
    $token->enableNTS();
    echo $token->toJWT();

?>
```

When i use this token in my javascript to start listening to endpoint, it is giving above error.

Javascript code is :

```
endpoint = new Twilio.Endpoint(token);

endpoint.listen().then(init,function (error) {
    console.log('Could not connect to Twilio: ' + error.message);
});
```

But, when i use token generated from twilio testing-tool, video cal works. I had updated my php twilio video sdk. But no change in result.
This was a working code earlier. Dont know what happened later! Does any one have an answer to solve this issue?

Comment: If you just run the PHP code above do you get an output when you print the echo $token->toJWT();

Comment: My php code is successfully giving access token. But when i use this token  in the same script(javascript side) it is giving authentication error.

Comment: Are you using your production or test credentials?

Comment: @philnash i am using production credential. It was working finely. Suddenly it stopped.

Comment: Was there anything you can think of that changed between it working and not working?

Comment: Nothing in program. I am using aws route 53. Can this be the reason?

Comment: I think we might have gone beyond the scope of StackOverflow right now. Best option would be to contact Twilio support by emailing help@twilio.com. Sorry I can't help right now.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did, which works in my case:

In my PHP file I have:

```
<?php
require_once('php/Services/Twilio.php'); // Loads the library

// You will need your Account Sid and a SigningKey Sid and Secret
// to generate an Access Token for your SDK endpoint to connect to Twilio.
$accountSid = "XXXX";
$signingKeySid = "YYYY";
$signingKeySecret = "ZZZZ";

$token = new Services_Twilio_AccessToken($signingKeySid, $accountSid, $signingKeySecret);
$token->addEndpointGrant("gonzalo");
$token->enableNTS();
?>
```

In my HTML code:

```
<span id='twilio_token' style='display: none;'><?php echo $token->toJWT()?></span>
```

In my Javascript:

```
var accessToken = document.getElementById('twilio_token').innerHTML;
console.log(accessToken);
// create an Endpoint and connect to Twilio
endpoint = new Twilio.Endpoint(accessToken);
endpoint.listen().then(
  endpointConnected,
  function (error) {
    log('Could not connect to Twilio: ' + error.message);
  }
);
```

When you do a console.log for your Twilio token is it valid?

Comment: access token is printing in console log. Later when i try listening, it is giving 'Could not connect to Twilio: Gateway responded with: 31201 Authentication failed'

Comment: If you create a new one what do you get? I would recommend to open a ticket to verify existing keys is still valid.

Comment: I tried with new signing keys but no result. I tried in another server, it works. I think twilio might have blocked my ip. Filed a ticket.

Comment: @spicyramen I am facing the same issue warnings in my consoles are `client WARN Failed to fetch Endpoint Configuration: {"message":"Invalid Access Token","code":20101,"user_error":true,"params":{"requestId":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}}twilio-video.js:6307:5
client WARN Failed to fetch ice servers from ECS: network_traversal_service not available`

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same issue with Twilio Video. In my case, server had a wrong date, so the generated token was invalid. After fixing the date, Twilio authentication started to work again.